# Need to update my EC2 environment regularly?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance, Python 3 environment with many installed features like SQLAlchemy, cherrypy, etc. How often do I need to update them? Are they updated automatically, or do I need to do this updating manually? I haven't found this information online.

Answer (score 0):

You EC2 instance will not be updated automatically. In this regard, it will behave exactly like a local machine. So, if you need to updates to your OS or other software, you will have to apply them manually.

However, manually running software update commands or even release upgrades is not the ideal scenario and something you may want to avoid in cloud environments.
Instead, you should think about how to automate your environment setup and configuration.
AWS provides some ways to run scripts at instance launch:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

This way, you could easily migrate to more up-to-data base images (AMIs) or change the hardware configuration of your instance.

Comment: I've checked out the link, so in plain language it means to update I need to first set up the script then stop and restart the instance regularly?

Comment: With this script you would be able to easily recreate the instance entirely and just terminate the old one. You would also have to store your data somewhere safe e.g. a separate EBS storage volume that you can attach to different instances.

Comment: To clarify, this script only runs on (re)starting an instance, what if my instance is a long-running one, it could mean running continuously for years without updating?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, if you run your instance continuously for years, it will run without updates. What I was trying to convey is that you are not really supposed to have the same instance run for years. In this case, just putting and additional computer under your desk would be much cheaper. You should aim to create a reproducible environment that can make use of the benefits cloud computing provides.